# Do I have to run cron every minute for Laravel's task scheduler, or is it OK to run less frequently?

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-scheduler

I've read [the relevant part of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling) and various guides, but I'm unclear as to whether Laravel *requires* the the cron to be run every minute, or whether it's OK to run less often, i.e. hourly, daily, weekly, etc, without causing issues?

In my case I need a script to run monthly; at the end of each month. It has to run at UTC-12 hours (i.e. the time at which the given calendar month will cease to exist everywhere on earth). Do I really need to run the cron job every *minute* for this, or does it suffice to run every hour? I would assume running it every hour will be fine without causing issues, but I'd like to confirm this.

Comment: Using Laravel's scheduler seems to be a solution for a problem you don't have. It handles multiple tasks on different schedules down to a per-minute granularity. If you only have one task to run once a month you might as well just schedule that in cron directly yourself.

Comment: OK, fair comment (although I'd still appreciate an actual answer to question, out of curiosity if nothing else). I assume if I set my cron to run hourly then Laravel would respond by running tasks I've scheduled as e.g. `->everyMinute();` once, on the hour, when my cron runs... ‍♂️

Comment: Regarding your suggestion, I'd still like to use Laravel to run the task though. Where would I point the script in that case?

Comment: **TL;DR**: it's not *required* as such, if you run it at less than the recommended frequency and it happens not to run in the minute when your task is scheduled to run your task **will not** be run. And I don't know how to run a task directly, sorry; I've only done a few months of Laravel/PHP and that was maybe a year ago!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, missed that one; it *does* answer my question, nice one :) I guess I'll just set the cron to run every minute like I'm told. It's not like I'm really saving more than a neglible amount of server power doing otherwise... I just wondered.

Answer (score -2):

Cron can be started at any time. You can "play" with Cron at this [site](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*).
If I understand the question correctly, the solution you need: 0 0 1 * *

This is a run at the beginning of each month. This is necessary because the Cron does not know when there are 31 days in a month and when there are 30 or less.

Or you could do something like this: 59 23 28-31 * *, but then the Cron will be triggered every month from the 28th to the 31st.

Comment: Hi, sorry, no, you haven't understood my question properly. I know how to schedule cron jobs on the server. I'm asking specifically about how Laravel responds to crons set less frequently than 1 minute.